# Efficient check if value exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I want to generate unique value and save it in database.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

I have two options (PSEUDO CODE):

1)

```
$allValues = 'SELECT unique_number FROM table'; //EXAMPLE!

$number = generateRandomString();

while(in_array(number, $allValues)) {
    $number = generateRandomString();
}
```

2)

```
function getUniqueNumber($uniqueNumber) {
    return 'SELECT unique_number FROM table WHERE unique_number = ' . $uniqueNumber; //EXAMPLE!
}

$number = generateRandomString();

while(getUniqueNumber($unique)) {
    $number = generateRandomString();
}
```

But both method are inefficient if I have over 100,000 records.

Is better way to check if value exists in database and generate new if exists?

I can use also Doctrine for this.

Comment: Why reinventing the whole wheel instead of using [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php) ?... your `generateRandomString()` won't be returning "unique" ids at all

Comment: Because my number has set rules, it can not be uniqid.

Comment: _Because my number has set rules..._ What rules? Don't you need **unique** ids?

Comment: Personally I would go for guidv4 type id, ive never had collisions using it. Alternately have a background task which runs once a day to fill a pool of unique ids then just link one to the row.

Comment: NOTE: from the docs, `uniqid` is not guaranteed to generate a 100% unique id (simply a microsecond stamp generated id, there can be 2 identical generated if created at the exact same moment). Do you really need to generate the id before the request? auto-increment is so simple.. if there are rules, we should know them to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you simple need a unique value in that table, the easiest way is to insert an auto-increment field on that table, so at every insert the database will creates this for you:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Then you can retrieve that value with `mysql_insert_id()` or `PDO::lastInsertId`